# add numbers down a column in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine, google-refine

I'd like to automatically number a column. Similar to Excel, where I can type "1" in one cell and the cells below it automatically get numbered 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. I don't know why I'm having so much trouble figuring out this function on Openrefine but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gail

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new column ("Add new column based on this column") with this Grel formula inside :

```
row.index + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Ettore. The row index doesn't really correspond with the row number I'd like to assign. I generally filter the data, then assign a new set of numbers. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Assuming that you have good reason to not use Excel, I'm afraid that the only solution is to export the filtered rows in a CSV file and then re-import it into a new OR project.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Ettore . I'd spent quite some time looking for a row index query function in the GREL documentation but it doesn't appear to mentioned there. Perhaps we should raise this with the developers?

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41268335/16592991) by Ettore Rizza already provides a solution for the common case. As the question author stated in a comment it does not work for his use case. He wants to add consecutive numbers to unfiltered rows.

For this you can use [records](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/exploring#rows-vs-records). The basic idea is to create records from the filtered data and use the record index as counter.

**Steps:**

1. With filters active add a new column with the expression `value`.
2. Move the new column to the beginning to use it as records.
3. With filters still active add a new column (or transform the first one) with the expression `row.record.index + 1`.

| Original | Filtered | Records | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | 1 |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| B | B | B | 2 |
| C | C | C | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Gail. I adapted the solution provided by Benjamin and I came up with this method:

Using rows:

1. with filters active add a new column with the expression `row.index + 1`
2. in this new column, sort cell values as numbers. Then sort >  reorder rows permanently (this will renumber the rows starting from 1)
3. still in the same column: edit cells > transform... > `row.index + (the number you want to start your incrementation with)`

This is the best solution I found, I don't know if there is an easier way.